# how to Include non-std folder in VS 2022 C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

I have a VS 2022 C# project that writes a file to a non-std folder in my web site. But when I publish the project that folder isn't included (i.e. it doesn't show up on the web server). How do I get that folder to be published & show up on the web server?

I create the folder via Project->New Folder & it does get created in the project structure. But when I publish the project that folder doesn't get published to the web server.

Comment: Is the folder empty? I have one of those, to which I’ve added a file - `ensure_folder_creation.txt` and marked the file as included

Comment: Can you provide detailed steps for publishing your project to the server to help us reproduce your issue?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.